# How can we dynamically move columns from right to left?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can we dynamically shift columns in the right to the left? I am trying to figure out how to use a function to do this automatically, so as new data is added to a sheet, it gets flipped from the right-most column to the left-most column.

Here is a screen shot of what I have now.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of what I am trying to get to, using some combination of Excel functions.

[image]

So, if new data is added to column F on the sheet named 'Input', the data automatically shows up in column B in the sheet named 'Output', and everything relative to that is flipped to the right.

Comment: Are you using Excel 365?

Comment: *the data **automatically** shows up* IF you use Excel 365, then maybe you can use formulas, but in older Excel version I'm afraid the auto extend part can be done only with VBA.

Comment: Can you include your own attempt to make this question suited for SO? Typically this is done with `FILTER()` and `SORTBY()`.

Comment: So have a data sheet where the latest data gets added to the right and then a summary sheet showing the 10 or 15 most recent - use index with match or similar to choose the most recent in the order you wish.

Comment: I used Index/Match. That worked fine. Can't believe I didn't think of it before. Thanks for point me in the right direction Solar Mike!!